# uwsgi options --wsgi-file and --module not recognized

Tags: wsgi, uwsgi, django-wsgi

I am trying to run a Django app using uwsgi. Most instructions I have found refer to a "--wsgi-file" and "--module" to specify the application, but "uwsgi" makes no mention of these options, and when I try and use them:

```
uwsgi -s /tmp/uwsgi.sock --master --module myapp.wsgi
uwsgi: unrecognized option '--module'
getopt_long() error
```

And

```
uwsgi -s /tmp/uwsgi.sock --master --wsgi-file myapp/wsgi.py
uwsgi: unrecognized option '--wsgi-file'
getopt_long() error
```

When I run it without either, I get:

```
uwsgi -s /tmp/uwsgi.sock --master 
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.9 (64bit) on [Fri Jul 10 11:12:04 2015] ***
compiled with version: 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11) on 23 April 2015 19:31:15
os: Linux-2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 10 17:01:00 EDT 2015
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 2
detected binary path: /usr/sbin/uwsgi
your processes number limit is 1024
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /tmp/uwsgi.sock fd 5
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 145536 bytes (142 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 26597)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 26598, cores: 1)
```

Why aren't these options recognized? How am I supposed to specify the app to load? What kind of garbage software is this? Should I go back to using Gunicorn?

Comment: How did you install uwsgi? pip?

Comment: @aaa90210 I found myself here because I had the maddening reaction as you did. LoL Most options didn't work, despite seeing countless examples online. Thanks for this post.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This means that the **python plugin** for uWSGI isn't installed or loaded. To verify run:

```
$ uwsgi --plugins-list
```

In general if you have build-essential python-dev etc., you can install via:

```
$ pip install uwsgi
```

On **Debian** or **Ubuntu** you can also install it via:

```
$ apt-get install uwsgi-plugin-python
```

On [Linux **Alpine**](http://www.alpinelinux.org/) you currently have to specify where it is:

```
$ apk add --update uwsgi-python
$ uwsgi --plugins-dir /usr/lib/uwsgi/ --need-plugin python --plugins-list
*** uWSGI loaded generic plugins ***

*** uWSGI loaded request plugins ***
0: python
...
```

Alternatively you can specify its full path via:

```
$ uwsgi --plugin /usr/lib/uwsgi/python_plugin.so --plugins-list
```

Comment: Still doesn't work for me. After installing both `uwsgi-plugin-python` and `uwsgi-plugin-python3` running ` uwsgi --http-socket :9090 --wsgi-file ./respond.py --plugin /usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins/python3_plugin.so` still gets me the "unrecognized option" response.

Comment: @Shadur what helped me with a similar problem was specifying the `--plugin ...` argument before any plugin-specific argument. In your case, you could try: `uwsgi --http-socket :9090 --plugin /usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins/python3_plugin.so --wsgi-file ./respond.py `

Comment: @shadur, you need to include --plugin python in your command after install https://stackoverflow.com/a/34638770/5042053

Answer (score 3):

Depending how you installed uwsgi also might also need to install the python plugin. e.g.

```
apt-get install uwsgi-plugin-python
```