# uwsgi unrecognized option '--wsgi-file'

Tags: python

I attempted to perform a run using uwsgi on a simple test file. This follows the instructions from ["this link"](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html).

However, it is throwing an error:
`unrecognized option '--wsgi-file`'

```
getopt_long() error
```

Getting more and more confused..

Comment: Could you post versions of applications/plugins you're using? :) helps us to figure out what to do.

Comment: hey what do you mean? check what i have on yum or my pip?

Comment: Yeah mostly django version, uwsgi version, things like that. Sorry for not mentioning.

Comment: Hey, thank you for replying. I am very new to infra too. I am using Django 1.8. For uwsgi, I just did a git clone from https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi.git and installed it.

Answer (score 7):

The thing that helps me is the option in comand line: --plugin python.

Comment: This worked for me, but for the fact it is now `--plugin python3`

Answer (score 2):

You need to install `uwsgi` plugin for python first. For Ubuntu you can do it by:

```
sudo apt-get install uwsgi-plugin-python
```

Comment: The package name on Ubuntu 20.04 is `uwsgi-plugin-python3`, but it doesn't change the error message.

Comment: I have this installed and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `uwsgi` in your `pip`.

```
pip install uwsgi
```