# I get unrecognized option '--wsgi-file' when trying to run uwsgi

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx, uwsgi

I'm setting up a test Python App on a Ubuntu server. I've installed Nginx, Python, and uWSGI. Nginx is able to host static files, but I get the error "uWSGI Error Python application not found" when I try to access a Python app.

I have created a file named "app.py", which is a simple "Hello World" app. This file is added to the same directory as the static HTML file. The static file comes up, so Nginx appears to be working.

When I tried to access the Python app, I got the error "uWSGI Error Python application not found". I searched for this error and one recommendation is from https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html. It mentions I had to run the following command:
`uwsgi --http :8000 --wsgi-file test.py`

I changed the port number and file name to what I have on my server. But I get the error:
`uwsgi: unrecognized option '--wsgi-file'`

I googled this error and a link mentioned I would have to install the python plugin: [uwsgi options --wsgi-file and --module not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31330905/uwsgi-options-wsgi-file-and-module-not-recognized)

But when I did the commands in this URL, it says I already have the newest version.

If I just type `uwsgi` on the command prompt, it would give me the message:
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
The -s/--socket option is missing and stdin is not a socket.

I was wondering if there are any items (e.g. programs, configuration settings) I need to look at to get uwsgi running and the web server able to host Python apps?

Answer (score 3):

You can try running uwsgi by explicitly stating the plugin you want to load:

```
uwsgi --http-socket :8000 --plugin python --wsgi-file test.py
```

Comment: ^^^this is the trick.  --plugin python3 in my case.